# Can an application run the code of another application?

Tags: c++, winapi

Hi,

I'm relatively new to C++ and WinAPI. So far I've managed to create an application, that is using the *CreateProcess* function and a *STARTUPINFO* structure to create a new desktop, launch inside that new desktop a new *explorer.exe* process and switch to it.

Next, because I wanted to be able to switch at any time between these two desktops, at a press of a key (LCTRL in my case), I've made another application that uses the S*etWindowsHookEx* function to create a global hook for the keyboard.

Because the hook is active only in the calling destkop, in the first app, using CreateProcess, before creating the explorer.exe process and switching to the new desktop, i've launched the executable of the second app twice: once in the current desktop and once in the new one.

Everything is working fine, I'm able to make the switch between desktops at any time, but now I've been asked to do something about the structure of the processes launched, somehow, to make the seconds app code run inside the first one, without creating a new process. Because this is my first post, I can't upload a snippet of the process tree, but the *procexp* application from [live.systernals](https://live.sysinternals.com/%22systernals%22) is showing the following structure:

---FirstApp.exe:

-------------SecondApp.exe (original desktop)

-------------explorer.exe (new desktop)

-------------SecondApp.exe (new desktop)

So basically, my question is: can I make the code of the application that hooks the keyboard run in the same thread as the FirstApp? This implementation, an app that starts these three processes, and the second app that hooks the keyboard, was my idea (I was not requested to do it this way, I was only asked to create a new desktop and switch between them), so I am open to suggestions towards making a better implementation for this problem too.

Comment: You need to use some form of IPC to communicate between the two processes.

Comment: Thanks, i'll do some reading about interprocess communications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possible since there is little difference between a DLL and an EXE on Windows, so I think you could try to export the routines from SecondApp and then import them in FirstApp with `LoadLibrary`.

But IMHO the clean way to do that is to break `SecondApp` in two pieces : a DLL containing code that actually does the job and an EXE that would be a simple frontend calling routines from the DLL.

That way, it will be trivial (and portable across different versions of Windows and SDK) to call the routines of the DLL from FirstApp.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to move the keyboard hook to a dll.